# How to handle a post request from a Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, post, get, web

So basically I would like to know how to handle a POST request from a python program, and store it on the website server so I can make a GET request to retrieve that information. I'm hoping you can help me. Currently this is my code:

```
import requests
url = 'mywebsitehere.com'

source_code = 'print('Hello World')

data = {'code': source_code, 'format': 'python'}

r = requests.post(url = url, data = data)

print(r.text)
```

I'm trying to send some code and the format for the code in the post request, but I'm not sure how to handle the post request once it reaches the website so other programs can access it with GET requests. I know how to actually send POST and GET requests in Python just not how to handle them once they reach the website/server. From my research, it seems like you have to make a PHP file or something and specify individual boxes or variables for the program to enter the information into.

I know it's a really noob question but I am just starting to get into more advanced stuff with Python and modules and stuff.

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered here but I would strongly suggest you to learn more about web development and maybe follow a tutorial for starters.

Comment: Are you looking for something like Flask? http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: i guess your question is related to STORING the data on the server side so you can serve it again to GET requests... usually, you'd use a database of some sort, and an ORM framework like Django or SQLAlchemy would probably be useful for a beginner.

Comment: Well thank you guys to whom responded but I'm going to take Selcuk's advice and learn more things about web development and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to learn more about general web development so instead of just barely understanding it I can get a good grasp on the post requests and actually develop my website into something custom rather than copying and pasting other peoples work without completely understanding it.

...also I'm not sure how to close a post to "answered" or something but yeah.